# UNDEFINED INDEX en formularios con php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy haciendo una base de datos de **formulario PHP con XAMPP**. Estoy creando una base de datos llamada *biblioteca*, la tabla que estoy empleando en este código se llama *empleados*.

El error que me da es con el tema de las declaraciones de las etiquetas al inicio `UNDEFINED INDEX`  en el php. Este error me sale en todas las etiquetas, pero no veo dónde estoy fallando. Paso tanto el formulario html como el php.

De guardarse, se guarda en la tabla, porque me aparecen al menos los datos de `DATE`, `BOOLEAN` y `FLOAT`, pero aparecen con todo a 0 y no logro localizar el fallo.

El orden de mi tabla es tal y como viene en el código.

### Mi formulario

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Biblioteca</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <h1>Empleados</h1>
    </header>

    <form action="tablaempleados.php" method="post"><br>

        DNI:<br>
        <input type="text" name="DNI" value="" placeholder="NIF"><br>
        NOMBRE:<br>
        <input type="text" name="NOMBRE" value="" placeholder="NAME"><br>
        APELLIDOS:<br>
        <input type="text" name="APELLIDOS" value="" placeholder="APELL"><br>
        DIRECCION:<br>
        <input type="text" name="DIRECCION" value="" placeholder="DIR"><br>
        F_NACIMIENTO:<br>
        <input type="text" name="F_NACIMIENTO" value="" placeholder="NACIMIENTO"><br>
        PUESTO:<br>
        <input type="text" name="PUESTO" value="" placeholder="SITIO"><br>
        TELEFONO FIJO:<br>
        <input type="text" name="TELEFONO FIJO" value="" placeholder="FIJO"><br>
        TELEFONO MOVIL:<br>
        <input type="text" name="TELEFONO MOVIL" value="" placeholder="MOVIL"><br>
        SUELDO:<br>
        <input type="text" name="SUELDO" value="" placeholder="PASTA"><br>
        CASADO:<br>
        <input type="text" name="CASADO" value="" placeholder="SI/NO"><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="submit">


    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

### Mi archivo PHP

```
    <?php  
    
    $dni= $_POST["NIF"];
    $nombre=$_POST["NAME"];
    $apellidos=$_POST["APELL"];
    $direccion=$_POST["DIR"];
    $f_nacimiento=$_POST["NACIMIENTO"];
    $puesto=$_POST["SITIO"];
    $fijo=$_POST["FIJO"];
    $movil=$_POST["MOVIL"];
    $sueldo=$_POST["PASTA"];
    $casado=$_POST["SI/NO"];
    
    
    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_usuario="root";
    $db_contra=NULL ;
    $db_nombre="biblioteca";
    
    
    
    
    
    $connexion = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);
    
    if( mysqli_connect_errno('$dni','$nombre','apellidos','$direccion','$f_nacimiento','$puesto','$fijo','$movil','$sueldo','$casado'))
      {
    
          echo "Hubo un problema con la base de datos error al conectar";
    
          exit() ;
      }
    
      mysqli_select_db($connexion,$db_nombre) or die ("No se encuentra la Base de 
     datos");
    
      mysqli_set_charset($connexion,"utf8");
    
    
          $instruccion_SQL = "INSERT INTO empleados VALUES()";
    
    
    
       $resultado = mysqli_query($connexion,$instruccion_SQL);
    
       if($resultado == FALSE)
       {
           echo "error en la consulta";
       }  else
       {
           echo "Registro guardado<br><br>";
           echo "<table><tr><td>dni:$dni</td></tr>";
           echo "<tr><td>nombre:$nombre</td></tr>" ;
            echo "<tr><td>apellidos:$apellidos</td></tr>" ;
             echo "<tr><td>direccion:$direccion</td></tr>" ;
              echo "<tr><td>f_nacimiento:$f_nacimiento</td></tr>" ;
               echo "<tr><td>puesto:$puesto</td></tr>" ;
                echo "<tr><td>fijo:$fijo</td> </tr>" ;
                echo "<tr><td>movil:$movil</td> </tr>" ;
                echo "<tr><td>sueldo:$sueldo</td> </tr>" ;
               echo "<tr><td>casado:$casado</td> </tr></table>" ;
    
    
       }
    
    
    
                mysqli_close($connexion);
    
    
    ?>
```

Comment: Debes usar el nombre (`name`) asignado a los campos en vez del `placeholder`, por ejemplo: `$dni= $_POST["NIF"];` debería ser `$dni= $_POST["DNI"];`

Comment: @Triby no ha funcionado, sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: XAMPP no tiene nada que ver aquí con la pregunta. No confundas una herramienta para gestionar bases de datos con un motor de base de datos propiamente dicho.

Comment: @padaleiana lo he puesto por si acaso, me ordenan hacerlo asi

Comment: A lo que voy es que no es necesario colocarlo en las etiquetas, ni mencionar a XAMPP siquiera, ya que tu motor de base de datos es MySQL (según las etiquetas), y tu problema aquí es con PHP.

Comment: @Maldo_96 si te funciona lo que te puse acepta mi respuesta como correcta con el check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya se donde esta tu fallo

Tu formulario :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Biblioteca</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <h1>Empleados</h1>
    </header>

    <form action="tablaempleados.php" method="post"><br>

        DNI:<br>
        <input type="text" name="DNI" value="" placeholder="NIF"><br>
        NOMBRE:<br>
        <input type="text" name="NOMBRE" value="" placeholder="NAME"><br>
        APELLIDOS:<br>
        <input type="text" name="APELLIDOS" value="" placeholder="APELL"><br>
        DIRECCION:<br>
        <input type="text" name="DIRECCION" value="" placeholder="DIR"><br>
        F_NACIMIENTO:<br>
        <input type="text" name="F_NACIMIENTO" value="" placeholder="NACIMIENTO"><br>
        PUESTO:<br>
        <input type="text" name="PUESTO" value="" placeholder="SITIO"><br>
        TELEFONO FIJO:<br>
        <input type="text" name="TELEFONO FIJO" value="" placeholder="FIJO"><br>
        TELEFONO MOVIL:<br>
        <input type="text" name="TELEFONO MOVIL" value="" placeholder="MOVIL"><br>
        SUELDO:<br>
        <input type="text" name="SUELDO" value="" placeholder="PASTA"><br>
        CASADO:<br>
        <input type="text" name="CASADO" value="" placeholder="SI/NO"><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="submit">


    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Si te fijas tu PHP `$dni= $_POST["NIF"];` no coincide con el **`name`** del formulario, `<input type="text" name="DNI" value="" placeholder="NIF"><br> DNI:<br>`

Entonces lugar de poner `$dni= $_POST["NIF"];` cambialo por `$dni= $_POST["DNI"];` Y asi con todos.

Te aplico los cambios.

```
<?php  
    
    $dni= $_POST["DNI"];
    $nombre=$_POST["NOMBRE"];
    $apellidos=$_POST["APELLIDOS"];
    $direccion=$_POST["DIRECCION"];
    $f_nacimiento=$_POST["F_NACIMIENTO"];
    $puesto=$_POST["PUESTO"];
    $fijo=$_POST["TELEFONO FIJO"];
    $movil=$_POST["TELEFONO MOVIL"];
    $sueldo=$_POST["TELEFONO"];
    $casado=$_POST["CASADO"];
    
    
    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_usuario="root";
    $db_contra=NULL ;
    $db_nombre="biblioteca";
    
    
    
    
    
    $connexion = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);
    
    if( mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
    
          echo "Hubo un problema con la base de datos error al conectar";
    
          exit() ;
      }
    
   mysqli_select_db($connexion,$db_nombre) or die ("No se encuentra la Base de datos");
    
   mysqli_set_charset($connexion,"utf8");
    
    
  $instruccion_SQL = "INSERT INTO empleados VALUES('$dni','$nombre','$apellidos','$direccion','$f_nacimiento','$puesto','$fijo','$movil','$sueldo','$casado')";
    
   $resultado = mysqli_query($connexion,$instruccion_SQL);
    
   if($resultado == FALSE){
     echo "error en la consulta";
   } else {
     echo "Registro guardado<br><br>";
     echo "<table><tr><td>dni:$dni</td></tr>";
     echo "<tr><td>nombre:$nombre</td></tr>" ;
     echo "<tr><td>apellidos:$apellidos</td></tr>" ;
     echo "<tr><td>direccion:$direccion</td></tr>" ;
     echo "<tr><td>f_nacimiento:$f_nacimiento</td></tr>" ;
     echo "<tr><td>puesto:$puesto</td></tr>" ;
     echo "<tr><td>fijo:$fijo</td> </tr>" ;
     echo "<tr><td>movil:$movil</td> </tr>" ;
     echo "<tr><td>sueldo:$sueldo</td> </tr>" ;
     echo "<tr><td>casado:$casado</td> </tr></table>" ;    
    }        
    mysqli_close($connexion);    
?>
```

Otro fallo que tienes es que tu **INSERT ... Esta vacio** añade tus datos, con tus columnas y solucionado. Si no te funciona es porque seguramente tengas un campo autoincremento como clave primaria en ese caso añade sustituye el **INSERT** ese por :

```
$instruccion_SQL = "INSERT INTO empleados VALUES('', '$dni','$nombre','$apellidos','$direccion','$f_nacimiento','$puesto','$fijo','$movil','$sueldo','$casado')";
```