# Conexión a MySQL dentro de IF

Tags: php, html, mysql

Saludos tengo este código el cual ejecuta bien excepto por la parte que dice if ($flag==1) que me gustaría que ejecutara el código dentro del if que hace un cambio en la base de datos.

Este es el código que esta dentro del if

```
$mysql_query("Insert IGNORE into voters
             Select * from barcode where id = escoger el numero de id;
             DELETE from barcode where id IN(SELECT id from voters)");
```

Este es el código en general

```
<?php
    include 'includes/conn.php';
    include 'includes/scripts.php'; 


    if (isset($_POST['no'])) {
        $sca=trim($_POST['no'],"");     
        $flag=0;
        $id="";
        $credentials="";
        $password="";
        $firstname="";
        $lastname="";
        $new2 ="SELECT * FROM `barcode`";
        $res2=mysqli_query($conn, $new2);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res2)){
                    if($row['credentials'] == $sca){
                        $flag=1;
                        $id=$row['id'];
                        $credentials=$row['credentials'];
                        $password=$row['password'];
                        $firstname=$row['firstname'];
                        $lastname=$row['lastname'];
                    }       
    }
    
    if ($flag==1) {
        
             $mysql_query("Insert IGNORE into voters
             Select * from barcode where id = escoger el numero de id;
             DELETE from barcode where id IN(SELECT id from voters)");
            
        echo
            header("refresh: .5");
    }

   else{
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger d-flex justify-content-center mt-3'>Product Not Found</div></div>";    
        return;         
        }
    }

mysqli_close($conn);
 
?>
```

Comment: donde se encuentra tu conexion en php con la base de datos antes del ``$mysql_query("Insert IGNORE into voters Select * from barcode where id = escoger el numero de id; DELETE from barcode where id IN(SELECT id from voters)");``

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [UNDEFINED INDEX en formularios con php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/526215/undefined-index-en-formularios-con-php)

Comment: Veo bastantes problemas en tu código: La lógica no se entiende, pues lees datos dentro de un `while`, para luego verificar algo y si se cumple dar el valor `1` a `$flag`, pero ¿qué sentido tiene eso? ¿No es mejor verificar la condición desde la misma consulta SQL? Por otra parte, dentro del `if ($flag==1) {` usas la extensión antigua `mysql_` y lanzas dos consultas, una `INSERT` y otra `DELETE` lo cual no es posible de este modo. Además, usas `echo` para los `header`, lo cual no tiene sentido tampoco. En fin, muchas cosas que mejorar en tu código, empezando por la lógica.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema esta en que estas llamando a una funcion con un $ por delante, lo que se utiliza para variables y no para funciones.

Tienes que cambiar dentro del if `$mysql_query("...");` por `mysql_query("...");`

y en caso de querer guardarlo en una variable tendras que poner `$query = mysql_query("...");`

Comment: Dónde sería el lugar correcto para ubicar la función? Dentro de las llaves {}  del if, antes o luego del echo? si lo dejo donde esta quitándole el $ no me carga la página.

Comment: @Steven5655 En principio el echo no haria falta, con poner header() bastaria. El tema aqui es que una vez hecho un echo no se pueden modificar los headers. Para solucionar esto puedes, por ejemplo, refrescar la pagina mediante un meta cambiando tu `echo header("refresh: .5");` por `echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='.5'>");`

Comment: Tengo entendido que usar el meta no es muy bueno para el SEO y no se que tipo de app/web estas desarrollando, asique si te viene mejor por temas de SEO podrias tranquilamente utilizar JavaScript añadiendo algo parecido a `echo("<script>location.reload();</script>")` @Steven5655